# ASP.NET - Unity - Read configuration section from external configuration file

Tags: configuration, unity-container

I want to integrate Unity in my app and I want it to use an external config file

The Unity initialization code is

```
var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = "unity.config" };
System.Configuration.Configuration configuration =
ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

// *** problem starts here ***
var unitySection = (UnityConfigurationSection)configuration.GetSection("unity");
var container = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration(unitySection);
```

Also I have external config file for unity, named "unity.config" with the following content

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <alias alias="IEmailConfigurator" type="Server.Common.Interfaces.IEmailConfigurator, Server.Common" />
  <alias alias="EmailConfigurator" type="Server.Common.EmailConfigurator, Server.Common" />

  <namespace name="Server.Common.Interfaces" />
  <namespace name="Server.Common" />

  <container>
    <register type="IEmailConfigurator" mapTo="EmailConfigurator" />
  </container>
</unity>
```

The problem is, in the line where I want to load unitySection, GetSection() returns null.

What could be the problem?

---

**EDIT**

I added

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
        </configSections>
```

However, now when I trace through code, in line

```
System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = //...
```

The configuration variable in initialized that FilePath property is C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\unity.config, and not my own unity.config file

Any idea how to reference the config file from web folder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the `<configuration>` and `<configSections>` element to your config file?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... What "and element" to add?

Comment: @bzamfir Sorry. Forgot to escape the xml tags.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660935%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx

Your external config file must also start from `<configuration>` tag, not `<unity>` tag

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved this yet. In Visual Studio, you have to ensure the following file properties for "Unity.config":

- Build Action -> "Content"
- Copy to Output Directory -> "Copy if newer" or "Copy Always"

I suggest "Copy Always" to ensure the current Unity configuration is always present after a build.

Answer (score 0):

To access the web folder, use the HttpServerUtility.MapPath method.

```
var mappedConfig = Server.MapPath("~/unity.config");
```

Server is a property of the Page, or use HttpContext.Current.Server.